# No longer able to aggregate by "Sum" for Dashboard / using "Chart for Work Items"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Working on updating the Dashboard in TFS for a new sprint. I have a chart which shows a "Chart for Work Items" widget with a "Stacked area" chart of all the stories which is stacked by "state". Then, I have the stories plotted using "Aggregation" and "sum" along with "Effort". This worked in the previous sprint. For the current sprint the Configuration area doesn't show "sum" anymore just "count". Showing number of stories isn't as meaningful as number of story point (effort).

(I thought perhaps the stories on my current sprint were generated with a different template and this is what broke the query or configuration tool for the plot. But I moved a story from previous sprint and let it be the only one in the current sprint and that did not work.)

The current version of TFS I'm running is "Version 15.117.27024.0"

**Previous sprint (works)**

[image]

**Current sprint (does not allow selecting Sum)**

[image]

Comment: Are there any differences between your "Sprint 8" query and your "Sprint 9" query, other than the iteration path? Double check the columns selected and the work item types shown in your results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't select the appropriated **Column Options** which are available for **Sum** action.

Just check the query "**Sprint9**", make sure you have selected the columns such as: `Effort`, `Remaining work`, `Completed work`  etc which are available for **Sum** action.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `VSTS` Column Options aren't just what columns you *see* on the query page - they reflect fields can be used by the query too.

Open the Column Options menu:

[image: Screenshot of VSTS Columns Option Add Menu]

Select Add Column and select field relevant, i.e, Story Points:

[image: Screenshot of VSTS Add Story Points]