# Azure DevOps dashboard: incremental aggregation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm trying to built a dashboard in Azure DevOps to follow the progress of completed User Stories over time. I would like to see how many User Stories we have completed on weekly basis. Unfortunately I can find a way to visualize this accumulated..

Is there anyway to make the aggregated incremental? So I'll be able to see, that we this week completed 6, last week 8 and the week before that 4.

Big thanks in advance.

// Nicklas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No longer able to aggregate by "Sum" for Dashboard / using "Chart for Work Items"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49077043/no-longer-able-to-aggregate-by-sum-for-dashboard-using-chart-for-work-items)

Comment: [Aggregate work tracking data using Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/aggregated-data-analytics?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a Widget that directly meets your needs. Here is a workaround you can refer to.

1. Add a date-sensitive tag to each of your User Stories. For example, the current week is 0704-0710, and the previous week is 0627-0703.
2. Create a shared query to query all user stories within a specified date range.You can refer to the following query:
   [image]
3. Add a widget called "Chart for Work Items".
   [image]

Configure the widget as shown in the figure: set Query to the query you just created, set Chart type to Column, and set Group by to Tags.

[image]

Then you can see your weekly user stories. It looks like this:
[image]